# Pandas doesn't place a value from series if index is not matching

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Any Idea for below,

```
dictList = {'name':["aparna", "pankaj", "sudhir", "Geeku", "feku"], 
    'degree': ["MTech", "BCA", "MTech", "MBA", "BCA"], 
    'score':[90, 40, 0, 98, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dictList)
score = df.loc[ df['degree'] == 'MTech', 'score'].reset_index(drop=True)
# wherever a values is zero, copy from previous values 
for i in range(score.size):
    if score[i] == 0 and i !=0:
        score[i] = score[i-1]
df.loc[ df['degree'] == 'MTech', 'score'] = score
print(df)


Final Output :: 
    name degree  score
0  aparna  MTech   90.0
1  pankaj    BCA   40.0
2  sudhir  MTech    NaN  ---> it should be 90.0, but index mismatch.
3   Geeku    MBA   98.0
4    feku    BCA    0.0
```

One way would be to preserve the old index and then do copy from prev value, Any better idea ?

Comment: this should be done for BCA too? wherever score is 0? what if there are more than 1 entry, do you want any value to be filled? or the previous value?

Comment: Only previous column value.

Comment: can you try `df['score']=df.assign(score=df.score.replace(0,np.nan)).groupby('degree')['score'].ffill()` ?

Comment: @anky_91 This solution is good...more pythonic way. Do u have idea of good pandas learning sources onlin...I have just started work in pandas.

Comment: I have learnt by practicing here in SO , so that worked?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be is to preserve the old index and then do copy from prev value, code below,

```
dictList = {'name':["aparna", "pankaj", "sudhir", "Geeku", "feku"], 
    'degree': ["MTech", "BCA", "MTech", "MBA", "BCA"], 
    'score':[90, 40, 0, 98, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dictList)
score = df.loc[ df['degree'] == 'MTech', 'score'].reset_index()
print(score)
# wherever a values is zero, copy from previous values
i=0 
for i in range(score['score'].size):
    if score.iloc[i, 1] == 0 and i != 0:
        score.iloc[i, 1] = score.iloc[i-1, 1]
    i+=1
df.loc[ df['degree'] == 'MTech', 'score'] = pd.Series(score['score'].tolist(), index=score['index'].tolist())
print(df)
```